# Add column to pandas dataframe indexed by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like

```
        some_data  another_id
id                                                            
312871     ...     abc
312977     ...     def
...
```

and a dictionary `letters = {"abc": "x", "def": "y"}`. I want to add `letters` as a column to my dataframe, but it is morally indexed by `another_id` so I can't just set `df["letters"] = letters`.

I'm sure there's a beautiful, elegant way to do this. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understand your question correct. Do you want something like:

```
df['letters'] = df['another_id'].map(letters)

        some_data another_id letters
id                                  
312871          5        abc       x
312977          6        def       y
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha!

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame({"letters": letters}), left_on="dscode", right_index=True)
```